# What video game is Paige playing while in the yogurt shop in Day Shift?

Tags: game-identification

In the 2022 movie *[Day Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_Shift_(film))*, Paige Jablonski, the daughter of the protagonist Bud Jablonski (played by Jamie Foxx), plays a first-person shooter mobile game on a tablet in the scene where they are in the yogurt shop. The weapon looks like a futuristic gun, and the enemies appear to be robots. The HUD consists of an ammo/clip counter on the top left of the screen, what looks like a green health bar in the center top, and a minimap on the top right. There is something that looks like a virtual directional pad on the bottom left of the screen, and a virtual fire button on the bottom right.

Clips and screenshots of the game being played:

[image]

<sub>Click/tap on an image below to view the higher-resolution, original image.</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]

##### What video game is Paige playing while in the yogurt shop in *Day Shift*?

Comment: The way the left "analog stick" moves without her thumb moving makes me wonder if its a real game or not.

Comment: My guess is that it would be some footage from an unreleased/prototype game by Netflix